# How to move files with same name and concatenate

Tags: shell-script, files, rename, cat

My directory structure is given below. I need to move all the folders from Test3 to Test2 and concatenate the files with same names

```
[jg@hpc Test2]$ tree
.
|-- Sample_1008
|   |-- 1008_ATCACG_L002_R1_001.fastq
|   |-- 1008_ATCACG_L002_R2_001.fastq
|   |-- 1008_ATCACG_L006_R1_001.fastq
|   `-- 1008_ATCACG_L006_R2_001.fastq
`-- Sample_1009
    |-- 1009_CGATGT_L002_R1_001.fastq
    |-- 1009_CGATGT_L002_R2_001.fastq
    |-- 1009_CGATGT_L006_R1_001.fastq
    `-- 1009_CGATGT_L006_R2_001.fastq

[jg@hpc Test3]$ tree
.
|-- Sample_1008
|   |-- 1008_ATCACG_L002_R1_001.fastq
|   |-- 1008_ATCACG_L002_R2_001.fastq
|   |-- 1008_ATCACG_L006_R1_001.fastq
|   `-- 1008_ATCACG_L006_R2_001.fastq
`-- Sample_1009
    |-- 1009_CGATGT_L002_R1_001.fastq
    |-- 1009_CGATGT_L002_R2_001.fastq
    |-- 1009_CGATGT_L006_R1_001.fastq
    `-- 1009_CGATGT_L006_R2_001.fastq
```

I tried

```
mv Test3/* /auto/dr-lc_sa1/Data/Test2
```

nothing worked but when I tried

```
cp -r Test3/* Test2/
```

It overwrites.

I want the files to be concatenated. At the end I need to have one Test2 directory and under every sample and their fastq files in the Test3 directory will be concatenated to corresponding fastq files in Test2 directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in way to concatenate a file and remove it, you'll have to break it into two steps.

In zsh, or in bash ≥4 after running `shopt -s globstar`, or in ksh after running `set -o globstar`:

```
cd Test3
for x in **/*.fastq; do
  cat "$x" >>"/auto/dr-lc_sa1/Data/Test2/$x" && rm "$x"
done
```

Without `**` to recurse into subdirectories, use `find`.

```
cd Test3
find . -name '*.fastq' -exec sh -c 'cat "$0" >>"/auto/dr-lc_sa1/Data/Test2/$0" && rm "$0"' {} \;
```

If `Test2` and `Test3` are on the same filesystem and there are many files under `Test3` that don't have a corresponding file in the destination, you can save some execution time by moving the file instead of concatenating it onto an empty file:

```
for x in **/*.fastq; do
  if [ -s "../Test2/$x" ]; then
    cat "$x" >>"/auto/dr-lc_sa1/Data/Test2/$x" && rm "$x"
  else
    mv "$x" "/auto/dr-lc_sa1/Data/Test2/$x"
  fi
done
```

Comment: I get this error [jg@hpc Data]$ sh move_and_concatenate.sh
: No such file or directoryne 1: cd: Test3
'ove_and_concatenate.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `do
'ove_and_concatenate.sh: line 2: `for x in **/*.fastq; do

Comment: I'm not bothered about removing files in Test3. File names in both Test2 and Test3 are same. All I want them to be concatenated.

Comment: @Jana If you want to keep the data under `Test3`, remove the `rm` or `mv` part and keep only `cat`. The error message doesn't make any sense if you copy-pasted the code: what exactly did you run?

Comment: @Giles This is what I did [jg@hpc Data]$ cat move_and_concatenate.sh
cd Test3
for x in **/*.fastq; do
  cat "$x" >>"/auto/dr-lc_sa1/Data/Test2/$x"
done[jg@hpc Data]$ sh move_and_concatenate.sh
: No such file or directoryne 1: cd: Test3
'ove_and_concatenate.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `do
'ove_and_concatenate.sh: line 2: `for x in **/*.fastq; do

Comment: @Jana I don't understand where those `'` are coming from. What shell is `sh`? You should start the script with a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line. You'll need ksh93 or bash or zsh to use `**`. Make sure the script doesn't have Windows line endings.

Comment: I'm new to linux. I think the cluster has CentOS and I assume it's c-shell. Can I run your script with shebang line on c-shell?

Comment: you may have better results using `zsh`, `bash` or `ksh` like he told you in his answer. `sh move_and_concatenate.sh` will run his non-posix only syntax script with a posix syntax only shell. Hence give you the error you got in your first comment of this answer.

Comment: I added shebang line and tried bash. It worked. Thanks a lot @Gilles and Ilua