# Concat files with similar name in multiple subdirectories to new file

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, cat

I am trying to concat all files with similar names but in different subdirectories.

I found this solution for exact file matches but I am not sure how to adapt it for partial matches

[Create new concatenated files of same name in multiple directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435794/create-new-concatenated-files-of-same-name-in-multiple-directories)

example file paths:

```
out/ch1/name1.1.assoc.txt
out/ch1/name2.1.assoc.txt
out/ch1/name3.1.assoc.txt

out/ch2/name1.2.assoc.txt
out/ch2/name2.2.assoc.txt
out/ch2/name3.2.assoc.txt
```

I have 20 different ch directories, and the final number in the file name matches the directory number.

I have a file with the names I am trying to concat.

```
name1 
name2
name3
```

How can I adapt this solution or concat this files in another way?
End result I would like one directory with one file for each name in my file list (in this example the end result would be 3 files called name1, name2 and name3).
we

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. So you have different files, do you want them to be merged by mask (e.g. all name1.*.txt go to name1 regardless of directory) or by directory (e.g. all files in ch1 go to name1) or by some other way (e.g. all *1.assoc.txt go to name1)? Can you please add this information to your question?

Comment: @rush I would like all name1.*.assoc.txt files to go to name1 regardless of directory. I edited the question for clarity

Answer (score 1):

In `zsh`:

```
for name (${(f)"$(<names.txt)"})
  cat -- out/ch<->/$name.<->.assoc.txt(.n) > outdir/$name
```

In `bash`:

```
zsh -c '
  for name (${(f)"$(<names.txt)"})
    cat -- out/ch<->/$name.<->.assoc.txt(.n) > outdir/$name
'
```

If you can't install `zsh`, you can do something approaching in `bash` and on a GNU system with:

```
readarray -t files < <(grep . names.txt)
shopt -s extglob failglob
for name in "${files[@]}"; do
  printf '%s\0' out/ch+([0123456789])/"$name".+([0123456789]).assoc.txt |
    sort -zV |
    xargs -r0 cat -- > outdir/"$name"
done
```

Comment: I am using bash not zsh and I get the following `bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('` on the first line

Comment: @keeman, yes `zsh` and `bash` are interpreters for two different languages. In `bash`, you'd run `zsh -c 'the code as shown'`

Comment: that results in the error `bash: zsh: command not found`

Comment: This works but it also copies all of the old files into `outdir`

Comment: @keenan, what *old files*?

Comment: all of the original .assoc.txt files appear in the output directory along with the concatenated files